# Is there a way to set the accessibility zoom increment?

Tags: macos, command-line, settings, accessibility, zoom

In accessibility, you can enable keyboard shortcuts to zoom, and then use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> to zoom in and out. But the zoom amount is too minimal, and each time I want to zoom in, I have to press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> or even more to get where I want to be. I'd estimate that the zoom amount for each increment is perhaps 5%, at most 10%, and I want it to be something like 20% or maybe even 30%

So, is there a terminal command (I'm assuming that's the answer) to edit some internal setting to update the increment value?

Answer (score 0):

You can set max & min zoom in Accessibility.
Using the default keys  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>+</kbd>   or  <kbd>-</kbd>  [I've never tried changing those keys to  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  ] If you hold the keys rather than tap,  it smoothly zooms in to max, or out to min. After initially reaching max or min it then jumps at key repeat rate either further in, or back towards normal.

[image]